# GetProp()/SetProp() using Atom under Windows x64

Tags: c++, windows

I use GetProp()/SetProp() with an Atom. Under x64 the 'lpString' of SetProp() is 64 bit long.

The MS doc says: "The atom must be placed in the low-order word of lpString; the high-order word must be zero."
See: https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/ms633568

Usually I use to set the lpString parameter which seem to ok under x32. But what is the definition of a "word" under x64 ?

GetProp(hwnd, (LPCTSTR) MAKELONG(atom, 0)) creates a warning under x64, which is right. But what else type conversion should be used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the warning? May need to cast it as (LPTSTR) instead.

Comment: The warning is: "Type cast conversion from LONG to LPTSTR of greater size." I am wondering if the MAKELONG() is still right under x64.

Comment: You might try something like: `#define MAKELONGLONG(lo, hi) ((LONGLONG)lo + ((LONGLONG)hi << 32))` to create your own macro to generate a 64-bit integer

Comment: Thank you for this hint, I know I could use typecasts, but is this an official MS statement about this issue? I'd like to write x86/x64 code without all kinds of #ifdefs...

Comment: If you don't want to use the ifdef you can manually OR the low and high order LONGs together using the same syntax: `(LONGLONG)atom`  That is perfectly valid x86 syntax

Comment: You are of course right, but why does MS not mention anything about the  x64 usage? GetPropW() is mentioned but not a word about the bad typecasts.

Comment: Did you try the @RaymondChen suggestion? MAKEINTATOM() -- looks like it casts to (LPTSTR) as well, and this is probably the Microsoft-sanctioned way to do it.

Comment: I created a special define and got rid of the warning. After so many Years of x64 coding it's still not clear to me, why there is nothing mentioned on the MS help pages.

Comment: How long have you done Windows coding? Prepare to be surprised again and again by the documentation... And not in a good way :-(

Answer (score 1):

What is meant is that the unsigned numeric value of the string pointer must be below 65535 (`0xFFFF`). All higher bits must be cleared. So in x64 the higher 48 bits must be zero. The term 'word' always refers to 16-bit values. The MS documentation is not updated for x64 and talks about 32-bit pointers as in x32.

The logic for the upper value of `0xFFFF` is that (allocated) memory in processes always start far above the `0xFFFF` address. Most executables are loaded at `0x40000` in x32 for instance. So a pointer can be "reused" to store an integer as long as the integer is below `0xFFFF` without any chance there will be memory at the address.